# Can javascript function name contain a space?

Tags: node.js, express, kraken.js

I copied the code from kraken. I don't understand why there is a space between `get` and `app()`. Can someone please explain what's going on here?

```
var kraken = {

    get app() {
        return this._app;
    },

    use: function (route, delegate) {
    //.....
    }
}
```

Comment: I found [this](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2013/12/es5-getters-setters/) explains everything.

Answer (score 2):

No, in javascript a function cannot contain spaces. The code you are showing is using the `get` keyword to bind a property to a object.

> [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get)
>
> Binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.

Have a look to [getters and setters in javascript](http://ajaxian.com/archives/getters-and-setters-in-javascript).

Comment: Based on my understanding, the code above should have the same effect as `function app(){}`. If I were correct, why do we need `get app(){}`

Comment: With get and set you can treat the name like a property and don't need to use function syntax.  For example: 
`object = { get app() { return "app"; }, app2: function() { return "app2"; } }`
`var someVar = object.app;`
`var someOtherVar = object.app2;`
The difference here is that the call for someVar will return the actual string value of "app".  The call for someOtherVar returns the function itself.  It's just a way of marking things as properties instead of functions but retaining functionality.  Just like getters/setters in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

It's a getter.

Check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get).

The function is `get` and it's exposing a property called `app`.

Comment: Yes, I read that already. But I still don't understand why do we need it. Since the effect is the same as `function app(){}`